# rails --v works for root user but not for other users

Tags: 14.04, permissions, rails, user-profile

I just setup a rails environment following https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04 and using the recommended option i.e. with rbenv. Though rails is installed and works properly but only for the root user. When some other user tries to use rails on the same system, following message appears

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Furthermore, you know, bundler doesn't like to be run (though runs but warns) as root user.

Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can install for the specific user either or try the below.

You might need to change your `/etc/gemrc` or `/root/.gemrc`. The default is set to:

```
gem: --user-install
```

Or you can use

```
gem install --no-user-install rails
```

Via: https://superuser.com/questions/475977/how-install-gem-rails-for-all-users-in-arch-linux